# correlation matrix by group on a single column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has a single column I want to calculate a correlation matrix for, by group. Each group has the same number of rows, but it's a big dataframe that I don't want to have to cast to wide due to memory constraints. Is there a way to do this in R without having to recast?

ex:

```
dt <- data.table(group=rep(1:100,each=100000), value=rnorm(100000*100))
some_corr_function_not_requiring_recast(dt, value, by=group)
```

should return a 100x100 matrix of correlations

Answer (score 2):

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(group=rep(1:5, each = 20), value = rnorm(20 * 5))
```

Here's are examples with base R

**1**

This works by first obtaining a list of unique elements for `group` and then running `cor` between `value` corresponding to all pairs of unique `group`.

```
groups = unique(dt$group)
sapply(1:length(groups), function(i)
    sapply(1:length(groups), function(j)
        cor(x = dt$value[dt$group == groups[i]], y = dt$value[dt$group == groups[j]])))
#            [,1]         [,2]       [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
#[1,]  1.00000000  0.436949356 0.04324370 -0.03960938  0.281518699
#[2,]  0.43694936  1.000000000 0.03976509 -0.06555478  0.005944951
#[3,]  0.04324370  0.039765093 1.00000000  0.33289052  0.211291403
#[4,] -0.03960938 -0.065554780 0.33289052  1.00000000 -0.183091610
#[5,]  0.28151870  0.005944951 0.21129140 -0.18309161  1.000000000
```

**2**

Another approach which also works without recasting but requires splitting `dt` into a list based on `group`.

```
temp = split(dt, dt$group)
sapply(1:length(temp), function(i)
    sapply(1:length(temp), function(j)
        cor(x = temp[[i]]$value, y = temp[[j]]$value)))
#            [,1]         [,2]       [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
#[1,]  1.00000000  0.436949356 0.04324370 -0.03960938  0.281518699
#[2,]  0.43694936  1.000000000 0.03976509 -0.06555478  0.005944951
#[3,]  0.04324370  0.039765093 1.00000000  0.33289052  0.211291403
#[4,] -0.03960938 -0.065554780 0.33289052  1.00000000 -0.183091610
#[5,]  0.28151870  0.005944951 0.21129140 -0.18309161  1.000000000
```

Comment: I just ended up doing it in a loop, seems like this isn't really easier to read or understand than just doing two for loops.

Comment: You say "without" using data.table but I see that you've used data.table for generating your dataset....? Data.table package doesn't seem to be available for R v3.4.4, FYI.